Самый быстрый алгоритм плиска по неизменяемым данным?
Ищу самый быстрый алгоритм поиска по большому файлу (до нескольких терабайт). Реализовываю с нуля, задача в общем виде - по запрошенной строке найти все строки из файла, имеющие такое начало. Таким образом поиск по хэшу не сработает. Но файл не изменяется,новые данные не добавляются, что упрощает работу. Сперва я реализовал просто бинарный поиск через перемещение указателя по файлу. Скорость порядка 200 запросов в секунду на ssd (с кэшированием всех промежуточных точек). Интерполяционный поиск пробовал, оказался медленнее из-за не такого эффективного кэширования. Затем я оптимизировал поиск при помощи деревьев. Разделил файл на несколько частей. Сперва извлëк все строки на букву А в отдельный файл, затем все на букву б и.т.д В общем, достал все подфайлы, которые больше 100 мб получались, остальные строки в оставил в исходном файле. Затем полученные файлы рекурсивно поделил на подфайлы аа, аб и.т.д до тех пор пока все файлы не стали меньше 100 мб. Скорость выросла до 1000 запросов в секунду. Делить файлы дальше нельзя из-за лимита на число открытых файлов да и общего замедления доступа к ним. Поэтому дальше я сделал внутри каждого файла структуру как в хэшмапе ну или по мотивам. В первой строке указано в каких точках файла начинается каждая буква алфавита (без учëта общего начала файла). В каждой из этих точек такое же оглавление для этого диапазона и следующей буквы. И так далее рекурсивно я расставил оглавления до тех пор, пока размер наибольшего оглавления не стал меньше 1 мегабайта. Найдя нужную точку применяем бинарный поиск. Дальше уменьшать размеры такого кластера нет смысла, так как есть риск переполнения оперативной памяти (все считанные оглавления кэшируются). Да и физической памяти много тратится. С таким алгоритмом скорость поиска стала 3000 запросов в секунду. Сложность уже линейная. Ищу способы ещë сильнее оптимизировать поиск. Накидайте идей, что можно попробовать и как оптимизировать ещë сильнее. Для кэширования доступно 64GB. Увеличение базы данных индексами допустимо на 20%. Общий размер базы 100 миллиардов строк.

Интересная задача. А нужно сами строки извлекать или их позиции в изначальном файле? Судя по бинарному поиску, строки даже уже и отсортированы в этом файле изначально?

Кажется тут неплохо бы посмотреть во упирается скорость. Вроде ничего сильно лучше префиксного дерева тут не сделать. Может твои 3000 RPS это просто предел считывания с диска…

@CrazyElf строки я могу менять местами как угодно. Нужно возвращать сами строки. На вход подаëтся искомая подстрока, нужно вернуть массив найденных строк, которые начинаются с искомой строки. Регистр не важен.

@Alexey Ten в скорость чтения с диска. Сейчас от объëма данных поиск уже не зависит, линейная сложность получилась. Но в итоге кэширование сжимает диапазон поиска до 1 мегабайта, который нужно прочесть. Либо целиком, либо бинарным поиском, а это примерно 10 произвольных чтений. Хотелось бы придумать, как оптимизировать сильнее. Может даже изменив всю концепцию на более удачную.

Тут интересно, насколько часто выдается ответ, что нет ни одного совпадения, если очень часто, то хорошей оптимизацией может быть фильтр Блума.

Из описания решения не видно, используется ли отображение файлов в память. Иногда ускоряет программу, но уж точно упрощает работу c файлом на чтение просто как с участком памяти.

Строка есть в файле в 95% случаев. И фильтр блума не подходит, так как он работает на хэшах. А в моëм случае поиск ведëтся по началу строки, а не по всей строке целиком. Отображение файлов в память работало чуть медленее, чем обычные переменные. Я думал использовать его что бы сильнее раздробить файлы и обойти ограничение OS на количество одновременно открытых файлов, но обнаружил, что отображение так же расходует эти лимиты. Но идеи очень здравые. Может ещë что-то приходит на ум?

Средняя длина строки и максимальная известны?

Измерил сейчас скорость чтения. Для случайных блоков по 4kb или меньше - 36000 чтений в секунду. То есть по 12 чтений на каждый запрос учитывая скорость 3к в секунду. Сейчас ведëтся бинарный поиск по отдельным блокам по 1 мегабайту, когда диапазон становится меньше 4кб, идëт считывание. Это 8 произвольных чтений+итоговое. Вроде как близко к потолку, но это без учëта многопоточности, а программа распаралелена. Если мерить скорость в двух потоках, получается уже 45000 произвольных чтений потолок диска, так что расти ещë есть куда.

@MBo  Средняя длина строки 300 символов. Максимальная - 20 тысяч символов примерно.

Ого... B-tree не рассматривали?

@MBo в бинарном дереве время поиска пропорционально логарифму двух, а в префиксном - логарифму 20-25 в зависимости от частотности букв. И плюс бинарное дерево очень сложно хранить в физической памяти и места много нужно.

Это не бинарное дерево, оно заточено как раз под чтение блоков с диска. Время логарифмическое.

Стройте trie и сериализуйте его в файл. Результатом поиска будет в точности поддерево, которое прямо в этом виде надо вычитать из файла и вернуть в качестве результата.

Вы можете зашарить образец файла? Желающие попробовать свои силы найдутся, я уже одного знаю.

Разделить задачу по нескольким дискам в нескольких серверах не подходит?

Я попробую оптимизировать через trie и b-tree, напишу если получится. Пример файла скинуть не могу, конфиденциальность, но там обычные слова, ключевые запросы и прочее. Сперва то, по чему будет вестись поиск, а дальше в этой строке нужная информация. Разделение по дискам понятный вариант, но если они будут на разных серверах, то время на передачу будет много больше времени поиска. А если на одном, то будет ограничение на число открытых файлов появляться. Да и места много тратится. Но я рассмотрю этот вариант, спасибо за советы

Вам важна скорость поиска для одного поцесса, который последовательно выдает запросы или суммарная скорость при параллельном исполнении нескольких процессов, выдающих запросы? Другими словами, что приоритетней, latency or throughput? И еще, алгоритм выдачи запросов должен быть синхронным (т.е. запрос 1 - ответ, запрос 2 - ответ, ...) или можно выдавать много запросов с асинхронным получением ответов? (да, я понимаю, что подобные алгоритмы могу сильно усложнить программирование)

@avp Система делается для api, которое должно отвечать максимально быстро,
причëм в одном запросе к апи может быть до нескольких десятков тысяч подзапросов и нужно их все выполнять до истечения времени ответа. И, да, нужно поддерживать очень много ассинхронных запросов.

@All, ну, если у вас много параллельных запросов с большим количеством подзапросов, а отвечать надо очень быстро, то без большого количества серверов с распределенной (и вероятно продублированной) между ними информации не обойтись. Понятно, что во всех точках получения запросов нужен некий индекс (по нескольким начальным байтам искомой строки), содержащий те сервера, на котрые нужно передавать каждый  подзапрос
